# convertir string "1 ,2 , 3" en array con valores numericos [1,2,3]

Tags: javascript, html5, json, javascript-objeto, jsonarray

Tengo actualmente en una variable lo siguiente:

```
var arr = "1,2,3"
```

Los datos llegan desde una consulta en base de datos y su columna es tipo texto, lo que requiero es convertir esa cadena de texto en un arreglo con los valores numericos para posterior poder utilizar para marcar unos checkbox, he intentado de la siguiente manera pero me sigue arrojando los datos como string no como un arreglo numerico.

necesito que lleguen de la siguiente forma:

```
[1,2,3]
```

esto que cada posicion sea de tipo numero, lo e intentado de esta manera pero siempre me devuelve un string

```
var arr = listas['spot'][0].checkDias
        JSON.stringify(arr);
         
        console.log(typeof arr)
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            $('input[name=semanaDia\\[\\]]')[arr[i]-1].checked = true;
        }
```

y es para poder marcar los checkbox con el for.

Muchas gracias,

Cordialmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de la manera que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

```js
var arr = "1,2,3" 
//Lo separa por sus comas
var arregloconvertido = arr.split(",")
//Lo convierte a integer
arreglodeenteros = arregloconvertido.map(a=>parseInt(a))
console.log(arreglodeenteros)
//Resultado esperado  =  [1,2,3] 

//Despues marcarias tus checkbox mas facilmente
//for (i = 0; i < arreglodeenteros .length; i++) {
//    $('input[name=semanaDia\\[\\]]')[arreglodeenteros [i]].checked = true;
//}
```

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo pero esa es lo que yo haria, espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @David081 esta genial,  funciono perfecto